# Ошибка при десериализации XML C#

Tags: c#, xml, десериализация

При попытке десериализации XML происходит ошибка. Прошу помощи чтобы разобраться с причиной ошибки.

```
Необработанное исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException" в 
System.Xml.dll                                                       
Дополнительные сведения: В документе XML (1, 1) присутствует ошибка.
```

Собственно есть веб-сервис, котором на вход я подаю список ИНН для получения потом обновлений по ним. При постановке на наблюдение, веб-сервис отдает ответ с ИНН и ОГРН клиентов, которые успешно поставились на наблюдение. Делаю это я следующим образом:
1) Получил xsd схему ответа

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfmonListItem">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="monListItem" nillable="true" type="monListItem"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="ArrayOfmonListItem" nillable="true" type="ArrayOfmonListItem"/>
<xs:complexType name="monListItem">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ogrn" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="inn" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

С помощью утилиты xsd.exe от VS 2015 перевел в классы.

Вот код моей программы. Сразу говорю, что ссылка на веб-сервис не рабочая, т.к. я не могу выложить свой купленный ключ доступа.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Specialized;


namespace Kontur
{
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
----
// <auto-generated>
//     Этот код создан программой.
//     Исполняемая версия:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Изменения в этом файле могут привести к неправильной работе и будут 
потеряны в случае
//     повторной генерации кода.
// </auto-generated>
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
----

using System.Xml.Serialization;

// 
// Этот исходный код был создан с помощью xsd, версия=4.6.1055.0.
// 


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = 
true)]
public partial class ArrayOfmonListItem
{

    private monListItem[] monListItemField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("monListItem", IsNullable = true)]
    public monListItem[] monListItem
    {
        get
        {
            return this.monListItemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.monListItemField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class monListItem
{

    private string ogrnField;

    private string innField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable = true)]
    public string ogrn
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ogrnField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.ogrnField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable = true)]
    public string inn
    {
        get
        {
            return this.innField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.innField = value;
        }
    }
}



    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://focus-api.kontur.ru/api3/monList?key=123124124&append=False ");
        request.Method = "POST";
        string postData = "6663003127,5260059340";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new 
XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayOfmonListItem));
        monListItem deserialized = 
(monListItem)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        //var test = deserialized.monListItem[0].inn;
        //string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the content.
         //Console.WriteLine(test);
        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: От сервиса вы получаете xml, json, какой формат ? Где ваши заголовки в Request (accept, content type ....) Приведите ту часть кода где ошибка, а не весь проект.

Comment: Мельком пробежался по публичной документации целевого сервиса... если правильно понял, то, по-умолчанию, он отдает JSON, чтобы отдавал XML нужно явно указать в параметрах запроса https://focus-api.kontur.ru/api3/index.html

Comment: Поставьте точку останова после получения ответа от сервера и до передачи в парсер XML, и посмотрите что внутри

Comment: @rdorn Вы правы, это я совсем проглядел, хотя делал уже подобную задачу только для GET запросов. там ссылка должна быть такая https://focus-api.kontur.ru/api3/monList?key==False&xml чтобы отдавал мне XML. По умолчанию JSON. Исправил, теперь вот такая вот ошибка.    Поставил точку останова на этом месте: monListItem deserialized = (monListItem)serializer.Deserialize(reader);  Необработанное исключение типа "System.InvalidCastException" в ConsoleApplication2.exe

Дополнительные сведения: Не удалось привести тип объекта "Kontur.ArrayOfmonListItem" к типу "Kontur.monListItem".

Comment: @rdorn А как посмотреть что внутри в студии?

Comment: `monListItem deserialized = 
(monListItem)serializer.Deserialize(reader);` => `ArrayOfmonListItem deserialized = 
(ArrayOfmonListItem)serializer.Deserialize(reader);`

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо большое за помощь, теперь заработало.